# Find similar objects that share the most tags

Tags: php, mysql, database, tagging

I have two tables `objects` and `tags`, each `object` having an id, and each `tag` having an `id` a `name` and a `parent` (the id of the object).

What I want to do is to choose an `object` then find other `objects` ordered by the amount of tags in common , e.g. to return the 5 most similar `objects`.

EDIT:

```
SELECT parent,COUNT(*) as count
FROM `tag` 
WHERE tag="house" OR tag="dog" OR tag="cat" 
GROUP BY parent 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This one does what I want, and I could find the obejcts tags "house,dog,cat" with another query before this one. Any idea how I could combine these two queries?

Comment: I agree with @sachleen - would be good to see an attempt first. Giving things an honest try is a good way to get practice! Try setting one up at SQLFiddle? `:)`

Comment: Sorry didn't have much to begin with, since I simply had no idea at all how to do that. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given one object, you can find its tags like this:

```
 SELECT t1.id
 FROM tags t1
 where t1.parent_id = ?
```

Building on that, you want to take that list of tags and find other parent_ids that share them.

```
 SELECT parent_id, count(*)
 FROM tags t2
 WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT t1.id
     FROM tags t1
     WHERE t1.parent_id = ?
     AND t1.id = t2.id
 )
 GROUP BY parent_id
```

That will give you a count of how many tags those other parent_ids share.

You can `ORDER BY count(*) desc` if you'd like to find the "most similar" rows first.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had to load the tags into my class anyways, so there was no need for the "combo" query. I had some more problems like not selecting the object itself etc . Won't test your solution but it looks fine, you shall be accepted ;)