# Finding at least one similar tag if possible

Tags: mysql, sql, tagging

I have a db with tables like **users**, **interests** and **tags**.

**users** table is something like this:

```
user_id  |  name  |  city
   15       John     New York
   18       Helen    Virgina
```

**interests** table is something like this:

```
interest_id  |  user_id  |  tag_id
    1              15         23
    2              15         24
    3              15         25
    4              18         23
    5              18         27
```

**tags** table is something like this:

```
tag_id  |  description
   23        Skiing
   24        TV
   25        Movies
   26        Music
   27        Seinfeld
```

Tables say that John and Helen are both interested in Skiing.

I want to make a sql query which will be resulted as John and Helen have 1 similar interest and echo them such as;

```
Helen 1 interest<br />
Jack 2 interests<br />
```

How can I do this?

And also, Are there any other better ways in terms of db schema?

As a newbie, I've look around and tried different implementations but not able to succeed.

Comment: how is the result formatted? by that i mean what are the columns you want to have on the result list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875040/find-similar-objects-that-share-the-most-tags?rq=1 is a similar solution.

Comment: @Sercan why they have `1` and `2` after their name?

Comment: @JW. 1 and 2 represents the number of similar interests.

Comment: @Sercan number of similar interests with who?

Comment: Your db schema is fine.

Comment: @JakubKania Think about John is doing this query and see he has 1 similar interest with Helen and 2 similar interests with Jack.

Comment: @Sercan There is no Jack in there :) The expected results should match the sample input.

Comment: @JakubKania You're right. Sorry about Jack. He should be listed, too. Let's say his interests are Skiing and TV.

Comment: I'm confused now. why do you need `tv` on the output? what's lacking with the answer below?

Comment: JW. Your answer looks OK. Please see the comment I've just made below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count how many interests user has in common with others:

```
SELECT u2.name, count(*)
FROM   interests AS i1 
       JOIN users AS u1 
         ON u1.user_id = i1.user_id 
       JOIN interests AS i2 
         ON i1.tag_id = i2.tag_id 
       JOIN users AS u2 
         ON u2.user_id = i2.user_id 
            AND u1.user_id <> u2.user_id 
       JOIN tags AS t 
         ON i1.tag_id = t.tag_id 
WHERE  u1.name = 'John'
GROUP BY u2.name;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80aad/1

As for the schema, the junction table would make more sense if it would be named users_tags. Also the id column on interests is not needed in this schema, the combination (user_id, tag_id) is a natural candidate for a primary key and you're gonna need to put UNIQUE index on it anyway.

Comment: Where should I put `DESC` to show Jack first before Helen as he shares more similar interests with John.

Comment: @Sercan `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` at the very end (but before the semicolon) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80aad/2